# Is std::optional's assignment operator 'effectively atomic' for address types?

Tags: c++, option-type

By sufficiently atomic I mean behaves in the same way as Linux address types. On Linux its guaranteed if you have a variable that represents an address be it a reference or a pointer assignment to it can only ever be observed atomically.

So you can do things like the following.

Defined somewhere

```
int *my_ptr = nullptr;
```

And then in two seperate threads you can have the code

```
my_ptr = new int();
```

And

```
if (my_ptr) {
    *my_ptr = 1;
}
```

And everything should work normally, meaning that my_ptr doesn't point to a garbage address that's half a mixture of the `nullptr` and half a mixture of the address returned by `new int()`. Its either `nullptr` and does nothing or its initialized and sets the value pointed to by `my_ptr` to `1`.

My question is does this same property apply if `my_ptr`'s type is changed to `std::optional<int*>` or even `std::optional<std::wrapped_reference<int>>`?

Comment: `if (my_ptr) { *my_ptr = 1;}` -- This is not atomic.  What if after that initial test and before the assignment, some other thread changes `my_ptr` to `nullptr`?

Comment: "On Linux its guaranteed if you have a variable that represents an address be it a reference or a pointer assignment to it can only ever be observed atomically." - Where did you learn that? Because that's just not true (or at least, not in the way you think). Your entire question is based on an incorrect assumption.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It was a bad choice of wording. I wasn't sure what to call that concept. I'm only planning on setting the variable once so in that case it would be fine.

Comment: @SebastianRedl I found the article in which it was mentioned the link is here. https://lwn.net/Articles/262464/.  The guy seems pretty reputable I think its unlikely he is mistaken. However the article is from 2007. If you scroll down to "Quick Quiz 2" you'll see it mentioned. I'll post the excerpt in my next comment though for convenience.

Comment: "Answer: On all systems running Linux, loads from and stores to pointers are atomic, that is, if a store to a pointer occurs at the same time as a load from that same pointer, the load will return either the initial value or the value stored, never some bitwise mashup of the two. In addition, the list_for_each_entry_rcu() always proceeds forward through the list, never looking back. Therefore, the list_for_each_entry_rcu() will either see the element being added by list_add_rcu(), or it will not, but either way, it will see a valid well-formed list."

Comment: @J.Rehbein But that's in the context of RCU operations, which form synchronization barriers to the compiler. Look at the place where the Quiz 2 question is asked. In that context, you have a `rcu_read_lock()` and a `rcu_read_unlock()` call. Using the shared pointers is only safe because it occurs within the critical section delineated by those calls. Outside, all bets are off.

Comment: @SebastianRedl There isn't any locked transaction being performed with ```list_add_rcu```. From the article "One key attribute of RCU is the ability to safely scan data, even though that data is being modified concurrently."  I checked the  [Linux kernel code](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/15a2bc4dbb9cfed1c661a657fcb10798150b7598/include/linux/rculist.h#L77-L87) and it confirms this. Mind that ```rcu_assign_pointer``` is just assignment with a memory fence it doesn't gurantee the pointer is written atomically. Although I couldn't find the definition for it unfortunately.

Comment: ... I could be wrong though and anyway my code relies on being cross platform so I'm just going use atomic variables like everyone says. Also heres another line directly from the [documentation](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/15a2bc4dbb9cfed1c661a657fcb10798150b7598/include/linux/rculist.h#L101-L103)

Answer (score 1):

Other answers are welcome because I'm not completely sure about this.

I've done a little research and from what I can tell `std::optional` isn't *effectively* atomic in the manner I describe at least with the [gcc standard library](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/d3a3029ca7489cb168d493de3d695809e84ffb0f/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/optional).

```
  template<typename... _Args>
    void
    _M_construct(_Args&&... __args)
    noexcept(is_nothrow_constructible_v<_Stored_type, _Args...>)
    {
      ::new ((void *) std::__addressof(this->_M_payload))
        _Stored_type(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
      this->_M_engaged = true;
    }
```

This seems to be the function used when creating the `std::optional`. In this case `this->_M_engaged` represents whether the `std::optional` is initialized or not, and the line above just stores the data type. Since there is nothing to prevent instruction reordering at runtime the results of `this->_M_engaged = true;` can be seen before the results of the preceding line that stores the actual datatype. So in the questions case in the segment of code (modified to support `std::optional`)

```
if (my_ptr.has_value()) {
    **my_ptr = 1;
}
```

If `my_ptr` is an `std::optional<int*>` then `my_ptr.has_value()` can return true even when `my_ptr.value()` returns `nullptr`.

I checked the function for reading the optional as well and there doesn't seem to be anything preventing instruction reordering either. Even in the includes it doesn't seem like there is anything of the sort.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer. Linux may be able say "we only run on platforms where conflicting accesses to a properly aligned, pointer-sized memory location are guaranteed to be atomic" but that doesn't mean the compiler has to actually offer any of the ordering guarantees of `std::atomic` variables.

Answer (score 1):

Linux has little to do with it; it's the compiler's business. That compiler is bound by an ABI, but the ABI does not say anything about this. So you fall back to the C++ standard, which makes it Undefined Behavior, both for `int*` and for `std::optional<anything>`.

That doesn't just mean "half an assignment", that also can mean "format your harddisk". The Linux-specific part may add some practical restrictions like "only if you run as root", but deleting $HOME is fair game.

Now, as to *why* this may happen, the basic reason is because the Standard says so. That means the optimizer is not restricted when it comes to touching your code. If it feels it's useful to temporarily use the storage for that pointer for other purposes, such as swapping out a register, then that's entirely fine - **precisely because other threads cannot see non-atomic updates**. Sure, the compiler could pick another memory location, but if the compiler just loaded your pointer into register A and then needs somewhere to store register B - hey, guess what's already in the CPU cache? There's only one thread that needs the pointer value, and that thread will use register A instead of memory.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm a bit confused for how you say the compiler can reuse the memory of my_ptr for something else. Because then even if access to it was facilitated with a mutex the value could contain garbage in a multithreaded environment. Does that mean you'd have to mark all variables that can be accessed in a multithreaded environment with ```volatile```? If so I've made a big mistake.

Comment: @J.Rehbein: Even worse, `volatile` doesn't work either. You need the mutex. At that point, the C++ standard kicks in, and it's no longer Undefined Behavior. The C++ Standard now tells you the use of the variable is _sequenced-after_ the mutex lock. In turn, the optimizer must make sure that outside the lock the memory is up to date. Typically the optimzier does this by marking the mutex lock and unlock points as points where the actual system state must match the logical state, i.e. memory is up to date at least down to cache levels. `std::atomic` is more fine-grained.

Comment: I'm kind of surprised the compiler is able to figure that out. I'd think there would be some degenerate halting problem type case where it just wouldn't know. That's very useful to know though. I think I should just probably read a book on this stuff at some point. I always knew multithreading was hard, but this just seems insane.

Comment: @J.Rehbein: There will be edge cases, yes. But in general you can't prove what the optimizer can't prove, so you can't abuse it. The Halting Theorem is non-constructive.

Answer (score 1):

> And everything should work normally, meaning that my_ptr doesn't point
> to a garbage address

Note that the C++11 Standard explicitly states that data race results in undefined behavior. Undefined behavior means your program may occasionally work "normally", but may also format your HDD. :-)